# How to sort strings regardless of capitalization without an array java

Tags: java, string, sorting

I'm supposed to write a program that sorts strings in ascending order and it's supposed to take capitalization into account. Here is my code:

```
public class CSCD210Lab5
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
      String str1, str2, str3, smallestStr, middleStr, largestStr;

      Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter your first string: ");
      str1=kb.next();
      System.out.print("Enter your second string: ");
      str2=kb.next();
      System.out.print("Enter your third string: ");
      str3=kb.next();

      smallestStr = str1;
      if (str2.charAt(0) < smallestStr.charAt(0))
         smallestStr = str2;
      if (str3.charAt(0) < smallestStr.charAt(0))
         smallestStr = str3;

      middleStr = str1;
      if ((str1.charAt(0) <= str2.charAt(0) && str2.charAt(0) <= str3.charAt(0)) ||     (str3.charAt(0) <= str2.charAt(0) && str2.charAt(0) <= str1.charAt(0)))
         middleStr = str2;
      if ((str2.charAt(0) <= str3.charAt(0) && str3.charAt(0) <= str1.charAt(0)) || (str1.charAt(0) <= str3.charAt(0) && str3.charAt(0) <= str2.charAt(0)))
         middleStr = str3;

      largestStr = str1;
      if (str2.charAt(0) > largestStr.charAt(0))
         largestStr = str2;
      if (str3.charAt(0) > largestStr.charAt(0))
         largestStr = str3;
      System.out.print("The Strings in Ascending Order Are: " + smallestStr + ", " + middleStr + ", " + largestStr);
    }
}
```

However, if I enter adam, Max and bob as prompts, it will sort them as "Max, adam, bob." How can I get it to ignore the capitalization? I'm not supposed to use an array.

Comment: Convert the Strings `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()` and then compare.

Comment: If you don't want tp use any array, you can use `TreeSet` & for upper or lower case @JNL given the answer

Answer (score 2):

Implement a `Comparator<String>` that uses `toLowerCase()` to compare:

```
public class SortIgnoreCase implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
        return s1.toLowerCase().compareTo(s2.toLowerCase());
    }
}

// ...
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
strings.add(str1);
strings.add(str2);
strings.add(str3);
Collections.sort(strings, new SortIgnoreCase());
```

Comment: I cannot use an array.

Comment: So just use the ``compare`` method

Answer (score 0):

Use a Comparator.

`public class StrIgnoreCaseComparator implements Comparator {
  public int compareTo(String val1, String val2) {
    return val1.toLowerCase().compareTo(va2.toLowerCase());
  }
}`

Comment: This solution is language dependent. For a language independent solution see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareToIgnoreCase(java.lang.String) and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/Collator.html#compare(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String). 
For an explanation see http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding